# Excel - Returning Data From A List Into Separate Columns Based On Fixed Criteria

Tags: excel, indexing, match

What I wish to do is return all values that match a criteria from a list, this criteria will be static .... as a simple example

- I have a list of all employee names in column A
- I wish to have a list of employees that contain the name 'John' in column B (this would include first, last or part of eg Johnson)
- I wish to have a list of all employees that DO NOT contain the name 'John' in column C

The name will always be 'John' so I would prefer to hard code it into the formula rather than have it be entered in a cell for lookup if possible.

As a side note I cannot use the advance filter as the real example is across multiple sheets.

Comment: You probably should move the dataset from excel to SQL. A requirement like that would be much simpler and faster to achieve. Just look at the complexity of the formula in the current answer, and it works only across 1 sheet for your first requirement... and is very likely very slow for large datasets.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this......
[image]

Enter following formula to `B2` cell as ***Array*** formula.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$20,SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("John",$A$2:$A$20)),ROW($A$2:$A$20)),ROWS($A$2:$A2))-1),"")
```

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to evaluate the formula as it is an array formula.